# Increase padding against surrounding font container in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

The following screen grab shows a Heading 2 piece of text with a shaded background colour applied.  This is just plain text (no tables, etc).

[image]

Is it possible to increase the 'padding' such that the space (indicated by the red lines) increases?

I know I can do this very easily with tables, using the cell padding option, but I want to stay clear of tables if possible.

I tried altering the Spacing figures, but that just increased the distance above/below the entire block.

Comment: That distance appears to be the same as the letter spacing, so I believe it is hard coded. Go to the advance tab of the `Font` window and see if you can adjust it there. Unfortunately, that will change all letter spacing.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but no luck - Word just expands the character spacing and retains the rest.  I'm surprised as I thought Word was based on an MS implementation of HTML, and it is easy to do with plain HTML!

Comment: That's what I thought it would do. Word in a great word processor for documents. When it comes to creativity of design, not so much.

Comment: @EvilDr: Doesn't modifying Line spacing in that same dialog do what you want?

Comment: @Karan: No sadly it doesn't.  I'd noted that in the post but it was my first thoughts too!

Comment: @EvilDr: You mentioned only the Before/After Paragraph spacing (and that's what is shown in the screenshot too), so I naturally thought you had not tried Line spacing. That's odd though, increasing Line spacing to double or similar should have helped.